# Dockerfile for .Net framework 4.5

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, .net-framework-version

I have a .Net framework 4.5 app which I need to run on an ECS.
I'm a newbie with docker so I tried to create a Dockerfile using the samples in https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-sdk.
But I couldn't see any .Net Image which is compatible with 4.5
Do you know which should I use, or how to change my Dockerfile correspondly?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnetapp.exe"]
```

Comment: Why change the dockerfile at all? .NET Framework 4.x versions are binary replacements, which means installing a newer one replaces the older runtime. Your 4.5 application isn't running on 4.5 to begin with. .NET Framework 4.5 went out of support *several* years ago. The earliest supported version is 4.5.2 but even that goes out of support in a few months and won't be found in any supported Windows version either. All supported Windows versions come with .NET Framework 4.6 at least.

Comment: You're using a container. This means you don't care what's available on the host. Why change the framework runtime?

Comment: Just use the 4.8 version which will support .Net Framework 4.5 apps

Comment: getting this when trying to build .net framework 4.5 project with 4.8 docker image, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2301,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*******, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.